# Python easy_install lxml error:none on mac os

Tags: python, easy-install

how can install lxml library for python2.7 on my intel mac?

Typing `easy_install lxml` in Terminal and getting next error after delay: `error: none`;
Internet connection is ok, setuptools is updated to latest version.

I have also downloaded .egg package manually but `easy_install lxml.egg` (replaced with actual package name ofcourse) gives me nothing too.

Log of `easy_install path_to_local_lxml.egg`

```
easy_install ~/Downloads/lxml-2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg 
Processing lxml-2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/easy_install", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('distribute==0.6.19', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.19-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1864, in main
with_ei_usage(lambda:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.19-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1845, in with_ei_usage
return f()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.19-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1868, in <lambda>
    distclass=DistributionWithoutHelpCommands, **kw
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
dist.run_commands()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.19-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 345, in run
self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.19-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 565, in easy_install
return self.install_item(None, spec, tmpdir, deps, True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.19-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 615, in install_item
dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.19-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 769, in install_eggs
return [self.install_egg(dist_filename, tmpdir)]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.19-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 820, in install_egg
dist = self.egg_distribution(egg_path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.19-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 811, in egg_distribution
metadata = EggMetadata(zipimport.zipimporter(egg_path))
zipimport.ZipImportError: not a Zip file: '/Users/dig/Downloads/lxml-2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg'
```